# Transferring only selected set of subfolders and not files in root folder using WinSCP

Tags: powershell, ftp, winscp, winscp-net

I have the following in a ps1 script and I am connecting over FTP using WinsCP to a Nitrado server with the goal of copying the folder called `backups` and the contents over to my pc. The issue I face is when I run the following it just returns the whole of the `minecraftbukkit` folder almost as if it ignores the mask other than `'*'` and just returns it all. I have tried using a mask of `"backups/"` however this then returns nothing and in the log output it says *File "/minecraftbukkit" excluded from transfer.*

I have tried this on my personal Linux server and it seemed to work so is this some issue based on the nitrado service? Or possibly their Linux server is missing a feature that is needed or something. I am open to any suggestions on how to make this work as intended. Thanks in advance.

```
try
{
    # Load WinSCP .NET assembly
     Add-Type -Path "D:\Users\username\Downloads\Minecraft stuff\Scripts\WinSCPnet.dll"
    
    $folderPath = 'D:\Users\username\Downloads\Minecraft stuff\test'
    $folderPath2 = '/minecraftbukkit'
    
    # Session.FileTransferProgress event handler
    
    function FileTransferProgress
    {
        param($e)
 
        # New line for every new file
        if (($script:lastFileName -ne $Null) -and
            ($script:lastFileName -ne $e.FileName))
        {
            Write-Host
        }
 
        # Print transfer progress
        Write-Host -NoNewline ("`r{0} ({1:P0})" -f $e.FileName, $e.FileProgress)
 
        # Remember a name of the last file reported
        $script:lastFileName = $e.FileName
    }

    $script:lastFileName = $Null
    
    # Setup session options
    $sessionOptions = New-Object WinSCP.SessionOptions -Property @{
        Protocol = [WinSCP.Protocol]::ftp
        HostName = "hostname"
        PortNumber = 21
        UserName = "username"
        Password = "password"
    }
 
    $session = New-Object WinSCP.Session

    try
    {
        # Will continuously report progress of transfer
        $session.add_FileTransferProgress( { FileTransferProgress($_) } )
        $session.SessionLogPath = "sessionlog.txt"
        # Connect
        $session.Open($sessionOptions)

        # Upload files
        $transferOptions = New-Object WinSCP.TransferOptions
        $transferOptions.TransferMode = [WinSCP.TransferMode]::Binary
        $transferOptions.FileMask = "backups/"
 
        [array]$transferResult += $session.GetFiles($folderPath2, $folderPath , $False, $transferOptions)
        
        # Throw on any error
        $transferResult.Check()
 
        # Print results
        foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Transfers)
        {
            Write-Host "Upload of $($transfer.FileName) succeeded"
        }

        foreach ($transfer in $transferResult.Failures)
        {
            Write-Host "Upload of $($transfer.FileName) Failed"
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        # Disconnect, clean up
        $session.Dispose()
    }
 
    exit 0
}
catch
{
    Write-Host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)"
    exit 1
}
```

Log (omitted beginning and usernames for privacy):

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.845 230 User logged in
> 2021-11-16 12:04:38.845 SYST
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.860 215 UNIX Type: L8
> 2021-11-16 12:04:38.860 FEAT
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.874 211-Features:
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.874  AUTH TLS
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.874  CCC
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.875  CLNT
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.875  EPRT
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.875  EPSV
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.875  HOST
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.875  LANG zh-CN;zh-TW;bg-BG;en-US;es-ES;fr-FR;it-IT;ja-JP;ko-KR;ru-RU
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.875  MDTM
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.875  MFF modify;UNIX.group;UNIX.mode;
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.875  MFMT
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.875  MLST modify*;perm*;size*;type*;unique*;UNIX.group*;UNIX.groupname*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.owner*;UNIX.ownername*;
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.875  PBSZ
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.875  PROT
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.876  REST STREAM
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.876  SIZE
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.876  SSCN
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.876  TVFS
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.876  UTF8
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.876 211 End
> 2021-11-16 12:04:38.876 CLNT WinSCP-release-5.19.2
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.891 200 OK
> 2021-11-16 12:04:38.891 OPTS UTF8 ON
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.909 200 UTF8 set to on
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.909 Script: Connected
. 2021-11-16 12:04:38.910 Connected
. 2021-11-16 12:04:38.910 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2021-11-16 12:04:38.910 Using FTP protocol.
. 2021-11-16 12:04:38.910 Doing startup conversation with host.
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.910 Script: Starting the session...
> 2021-11-16 12:04:38.910 PWD
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.923 257 "/" is the current directory
. 2021-11-16 12:04:38.924 Getting current directory name.
. 2021-11-16 12:04:38.924 Startup conversation with host finished.
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.924 Script: Session started.
< 2021-11-16 12:04:38.924 Script: Active session: [1] 
> 2021-11-16 12:04:39.643 Script: pwd
< 2021-11-16 12:04:39.644 Script: /
> 2021-11-16 12:04:39.716 Script: get  -nopermissions -preservetime -transfer="binary" -filemask="backups/"  -- "/minecraftbukkit" "D:\Users\username\Downloads\Minecraft stuff\test"
. 2021-11-16 12:04:39.716 Listing file "/minecraftbukkit".
. 2021-11-16 12:04:39.717 Retrieving file information...
> 2021-11-16 12:04:39.717 MLST /minecraftbukkit
< 2021-11-16 12:04:39.731 250-Start of list for /minecraftbukkit
< 2021-11-16 12:04:39.732  modify=20211112092756;perm=flcdmpe;type=dir;unique=10304U4064951C;UNIX.group=11257;UNIX.groupname=11257;UNIX.mode=0700;UNIX.owner=6258;UNIX.ownername=; /minecraftbukkit
< 2021-11-16 12:04:39.732 250 End of list
. 2021-11-16 12:04:39.732  modify=20211112092756;perm=flcdmpe;type=dir;unique=10304U4064951C;UNIX.group=11257;UNIX.groupname=11257;UNIX.mode=0700;UNIX.owner=6258;UNIX.ownername=; /minecraftbukkit
. 2021-11-16 12:04:39.732 Retrieving file information successful
. 2021-11-16 12:04:39.733 minecraftbukkit;D;0;2021-11-12T09:27:56.000Z;3;"" [0];"11257" [0];rwx------;0
. 2021-11-16 12:04:39.733 Copying 1 files/directories to local directory "D:\Users\username\Downloads\Minecraft stuff\" - total size: 0
. 2021-11-16 12:04:39.733   PrTime: Yes; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100; Resume: S (102400); CalcS: Yes; Mask: test
. 2021-11-16 12:04:39.733   TM: B; ClAr: No; RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 0; NewerOnly: No; EncryptNewFiles: Yes; ExcludeHiddenFiles: No; ExcludeEmptyDirectories: No; InclM: backups/; ResumeL: 0
. 2021-11-16 12:04:39.733   AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml
. 2021-11-16 12:04:39.733 File "/minecraftbukkit" excluded from transfer
* 2021-11-16 12:04:39.733 (ESkipFile) 
. 2021-11-16 12:04:39.733 Copying finished: Transferred: 0, Elapsed: 0:00:00, CPS: 0/s
> 2021-11-16 12:04:39.826 Script: exit
. 2021-11-16 12:04:39.826 Script: Exit code: 0
. 2021-11-16 12:04:39.830 Disconnected from server
```

In terms of folder structure this is it just a regular bukkit layout and I am trying to pull the backups folder as shown:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to download `backups` specifically, do it explicitly:

```
$folderPath2 = '/minecraftbukkit/backups/*'
```

---

If your point was to make the "filemask" variable, your problem is that your are giving WinSCP conflicting masks. You are telling it to download everything that has name `minecraftbukkit` and `backups` at the same time. So it does not download anything.

If you want to tell WinSCP to apply the mask to files in `minecraftbukkit` and not to the `minecraftbukkit` directly, you need to select files in the files, not the folder itself, by adding `/*`:

```
$folderPath2 = '/minecraftbukkit/*'
```

As the documentation for the [`remotePath` parameter](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_session_getfiles#remotepath) says:

> Full path to remote directory followed by slash and [wildcard](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_wildcard) to select files or subdirectories to download. To download all files in a directory, use mask `*`.

---

It's more complicated if you want to do recursive transfers. Then you need to use [path mask](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask#path), like:

```
*/plugins/*;*/plugins/*/*;*/backups/*;*/backups/*/*
```

But you will need to enable [`ExcludeEmptyDirectories`](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/rawtransfersettings#excludeemptydirectories) to avoid "downloading" files that contains no matches files. Note that WinSCP will iterate all folders unnecessarily anyway.

---

Better option might be to select the folders (what implicitly includes all subfolders and contained files), but exclude all files directly in the root folder, like:

```
plugins/; backups/ | /minecraftbukkit/*
```

Since WinSCP 5.20.1, you can use masks relative to the root of the operation (i.e. `/minecraftbukkit`):

```
plugins/; backups/ | ./*
```